# Remove-printer -Name - How to remove multiple printers in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I cannot find a way to remove multiple printers using this comand:

```
Remove-printer -Name "Name"
```

I've already tried with:

```
Remove-printer -Name "Name,Name1,Name2"
Remove-printer -Name "Name|Name1|Name2"
```

Is there a way to remove multiple printers using only one command?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the cmdlet remove-printer supports an array for the parameter name, so you can do:

```
#Define Array
$names = @('name1','name2','name3')
#Remove printer
remove-printer -name $names
```